# How to setup Xamarin with Visual Studio 2015 completely with Offline setups?

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, xamarin.ios

I have visual Studio 2015 enterprise iso but after successful installation, it asks me to install a lot components whenever i try to start something like: mobile apps, web app with xamarin, or apache cordava components, etc.

Right now i need some downloads that i dont know and asking here so that i can install them to my computer anytime (Offline). So i can start developing apps without any extra downloads.

My Current requirements are: 
Full installation of Apache Cordava, GTK, Type Script, Angular 2, React, Xamarin and other tools needed to develop mobile apps for Windows, iOS or Android, any.

Please guide for full offline installation for these components.

Thanks
Rupali

Comment: it seems quite a broad question + what is the problem with having everything running on the internet ?

Comment: @Shubhank
You didn't answer the question rather you asked another question that is not related to this one here because I want to install all that stuff whenever i want on a fresh system. can't go and connect to internet every time if in case im on the go. If i have all that stuff in Dumps, i can install any time , anywhere.
Note: Updates are not an issue here.

Comment: It is a useful question.  Perhaps you wish to set six developers up to do Xamarin development.  It does seem silly to be forced to download hundreds of megabytes of installers multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know there is not offline installion. Maybe in feature will see xamarin and other features built in with visualstudio 2015

Comment: Many developers are having dumps of all required stuff. Why can't we do then? Means there is definitely some work around.